# Bus Ticket Booking Form - Mobile

Tags: mobile, android, forms

While designing a Bus booking site - i was thinking on the number of inputs i will require for searching all the buses between two routes.

The Web version contains these forms

1. One Way/ Round Trip (Radio Button)
2. From (Place)
3. Destination (Place)
4. Date (onwards and return)
5. Number of Passengers and option to check if all passengers are women
6. Type of Bus

For the mobile app i feel having too many input may not want users to use the form

Can i just have

1. One Way/Round Trip (radio button style)
2. From
3. Destination
4. Date (onwards)
5. Date (return)
6. No of passengers

Any suggestions from you guys ?

Comment: Harsha - What is the context of use for this mobile app? Could you flip the problem on it's head by using the current location as the start point?

Comment: nope. its ticket booking for bus travel. like flight tickets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to ask for From and Destination, and then show all the available options for this trip: bus routes, their schedule, bus types, and price (!). This way user needs to fill just two fields and then chooses from all the possibilities she has.

From and Destination are required and usually known when you are planning your travel, but it is often the case that you have no strict restrictions for bus types or dates (any time on the following week).

This is much more usable then asking for everything including bus type and then showing "no results" to the user.

Comment: just wondering.. how and when to give the filtering capabilities ? especially the date..

Comment: @HarshaMV may be on results page? You see all results for the next week and could specify/change the date if it’s not what you want / there’s too much info

Comment: okay. i am just wondering on android using the design principles how to give the filter to the user.